# Select rows based on values in query

Tags: sql, sqlite

My table :

| id | role |
| --- | --- |
| b | f |
| b | s |
| b | g |
| a | s |
| a | f |
| c | f |

I want a distinct `id` but with corresponding `role`, with this logic:

```
If g exists select g if not 
if s exists select s if not 
if f exists select f.
```

Query should yield :

| id | role |
| --- | --- |
| b | g |
| a | s |
| c | f |

I tried `group by id`, but `role` cannot be sorted in a useful order.

Comment: Show actual data sample and explain better the logic. The explanation above does really make much sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select  id
       ,role
from    (
        select  *
                ,rank() over(partition by id order by case when role = 'g' then 2 when role = 's' then 1 end desc) as rnk
        from    t
        ) t
where   rnk = 1
```

| id | role |
| --- | --- |
| a | s |
| b | g |
| c | f |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/MNFuo826)